# Flexible Div height between fixed Divs

Tags: html, css, height, fixed

I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.

Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks

[Image: Div arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg13V.png)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eucvhskn/ Try to avoid fixed divs. Just a matter of opionion

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ufpt8n6h/)**

```
.clr{clear: both;}
div{text-align: center;}
.divA{background-color: #f0d5da;height: 87px;}
.divB{background-color: #c6e3a8;height: 50px;}
.divC1{background-color: #f33e47;min-height: 200px;width: 50%;float: left;}
.midcontainer{padding-bottom: 40px;}
.divC2{background-color: #fc575f;min-height: 200px;width: 50%;float: right;}
.divD{background-color: #f0d5da;height: 40px;position: fixed;bottom:0;width: 100%;}
```

html:-

```
<div class="divA">
    DIV A
</div>
<div class="divB">
    DIV B
</div>
<div class="midcontainer">
    <div class="divC1">DIV C1</div>
    <div class="divC2">DIV C2</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="divD">DIV D</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much! this almost gets me there. the only issue is: i'd like the midcontainer-content to scroll only within this container if its size expands. currently, everything (except fixed bottom) scrolls. you have an idea? thank you.

Comment: mh.. basically this is what i wanted to avoid – defining height for the midcontainer divs. but thank you, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

## General

Fixing the position of your headers and footers and adding top and bottom margin to the inner columns is close to what you have mocked up.

## Equal Heights

For faux equal heights wrap the inner columns and apply the background color.

## Options

You could look into using table css and classes. There are also javascript solutions.

### Click run code snippet below to preview

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  }

.header, .subhead {
  background-color: #f2d5da;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  }

.subhead {
  background-color: #c3e3ac;
  top: 50px;
  }

.container {
  background-color: #ff535e;
  min-height: 100vh;
  }

.column1, .column2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

.footer {
  background-color: #f2d5da;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  }

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  A
</div>
<div class="subhead">
  B
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="column1">
  C1
  <p>Umami synth Neutra, cardigan seitan squid slow-carb wolf mumblecore Godard paleo bespoke brunch pop-up. Asymmetrical skateboard banjo beard brunch. Drinking vinegar shabby chic next level American Apparel raw denim Truffaut Godard occupy. Wolf PBR&B VHS, Kickstarter selfies pug Brooklyn mlkshk lomo seitan distillery chambray Tonx. Vegan keffiyeh slow-carb cornhole. Etsy artisan drinking vinegar Brooklyn roof party. 3 wolf moon butcher single-origin coffee church-key Pinterest typewriter Wes Anderson.</p>
</div>
<div class="column2">
  C2
  <p>Umami synth Neutra, cardigan seitan squid slow-carb wolf mumblecore Godard paleo bespoke brunch pop-up. Asymmetrical skateboard banjo beard brunch. Drinking vinegar shabby chic next level American Apparel raw denim Truffaut Godard occupy. Wolf PBR&B VHS, Kickstarter selfies pug Brooklyn mlkshk lomo seitan distillery chambray Tonx. Vegan keffiyeh slow-carb cornhole. Etsy artisan drinking vinegar Brooklyn roof party. 3 wolf moon butcher single-origin coffee church-key Pinterest typewriter Wes Anderson.</p>
  <p>Umami synth Neutra, cardigan seitan squid slow-carb wolf mumblecore Godard paleo bespoke brunch pop-up. Asymmetrical skateboard banjo beard brunch. Drinking vinegar shabby chic next level American Apparel raw denim Truffaut Godard occupy. Wolf PBR&B VHS, Kickstarter selfies pug Brooklyn mlkshk lomo seitan distillery chambray Tonx. Vegan keffiyeh slow-carb cornhole. Etsy artisan drinking vinegar Brooklyn roof party. 3 wolf moon butcher single-origin coffee church-key Pinterest typewriter Wes Anderson.</p>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  D
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, richard. the thing is: in your demo, the whole page has a scrollbar. ideally, i'd like to have one only on the column1-div. is this possible?

Comment: Only on the first column independent of the second column or shared across both?

Comment: only the first column. the second column should never scroll. thanks thanks thanks (:

Comment: If you add overflow:hidden; to the body class of Maddy's answer it will stop the other scrolling. Looks like you have enough here to work from.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
<body>

<div id="A" style="
    height: 100px;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
    background: lavenderblush;
    position: absolute;
"><p>DIV A</p></div>    


<div id="B" style="
    height: 50px;
    background: lightgreen;
 top:100px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
    position: absolute;
"><p>DIV B</p></div>

<div id="C1" style="
 top:150px;
 left:0px;
 bottom:50px;
    width: 50%;
    background: lightcoral;
    position: absolute;
">
<div id="content_c1" style="
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightyellow;
    opacity: .5;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;

">
<p>DIV C1</p>
<p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p>
</div>
</div>


<div id="C2" style="
 top:150px;
 right:0px;
 bottom:50px;
    width: 50%;
    background: lightcoral;
    position: absolute;
">
<div id="content_c1" style="
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightyellow;
    opacity: .5;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;

">
<p>DIV C2</p>
<p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p><p>I'm somewhat of a novice and have a question which I suppose is rather simple.
I'd like to build a more or less flexible layout having fixed divs on top and bottom but a flexible div in between. I've made a sketch as I can't explain it any better than that way.</p><p>Would be gracious if anyone could give me a start.
Thanks </p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="D" style="
    height: 50px;
    background: lavenderblush;
    bottom:0px;
 left:0px;
 right:0px;

    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
"><p>DIV D</p></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

If you run this code snippet also click "Full page".